# How to render forms based on selected settings in django

Tags: django

I want to render forms based on selected settings.
I have a journal type below:

```
class Journal(models.Model):
    journalsId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name =  models.CharField(max_length=500)
    acname =  models.CharField(max_length=100)
    issnprint = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    issnonline =  models.CharField(max_length=500)
    logo =  models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="images/journals/")
    msg =  models.CharField(max_length=500)
    status =  models.BooleanField(default=True)

    c1_form_checkbox = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    c2_form_checkbox = models.BooleanField(default=True)    
    c3_form_checkbox = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    .
    .
    c19_form_checkbox = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Each C*_form is a html file.

Lets say I have below Journal Types:

1. A -> 5 random Checboxes are selected
2. B -> 10 random Checkboxes are selected

So when I select any journal type to fill the forms, How can I render these C*_form.html in order?

Thanks

Comment: probably multiple select should be better.

Answer (score 1):

probably multiple select should be better than 20 fields.
If you want on render render additional htmls in html. for example i take EditView from DGCBV:

```
class MyEditView(EditView):
    template_name = 'main.html'
    ...
    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['form_templates'] = []
        for index in range (1, 20):
            if getattr(self.object, f'c{index}_form_checkbox', False):
                kwargs['form_templates'] += [f'C{index}_form.html']
        return super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
```

in `main.html`:

```
{% for form_template in form_templates %}
    {% includes form_template %}
{% endfor %}
```

This help you to render many additional templates into main template render. And it depends on `checkboxes` in your `Journal` object.

Comment: This looks promising, I will tweak it according to my need, Thanks